# What is it called when you sell and reinvest to pay lower taxes?

Tags: united-states, investing, terminology, capital-gains-tax

Every year or so, I sell my investments and then immediately buy them again. I do this because I'm in a low enough tax bracket that I don't have to pay capital gains on my long term investments, so I'm trying to capture as many gains as I can before I rise into a higher tax bracket. I talked to someone a while ago about this and he had a name for it, but I can't remember what it is. Does anyone know what this strategy is called?

In case it is relevant, my investments are all index funds.

Comment: Isn't this tax evasion?

Comment: @SethGreylyn: Nope. Abusing loopholes with full reporting is not tax evasion. If the IRS wants to call you on it they have all the information in front of them.

Comment: @SethGreylyn A wash sale would be, but that involves selling securities at a *loss* and then buying them back.

Comment: The UK term for this is "bed and breakfast" - see http://www.investopedia.com/terms/b/bed-and-breakfast-deal.asp.  Comment as a) I don't have enough rep to answer this locked question; b) the OP is asking about US, not UK.

Comment: @SethGreylyn It's tax _avoidance_, rather.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It sounds like you're describing [tax gain harvesting](https://www.bogleheads.org/wiki/Tax_gain_harvesting), where you intentionally realize capital gains in a low-tax-rate period in order to increase your cost basis and reduce future capital gains at higher rates.

Comment: Cool! I don't believe that was the term he used, but it definitely fits the bill. I'll accept your answer unless someone provides a clearly superior one soon.

Comment: Here in the UK, we call it "CGT harvesting".

Comment: In the UK we also call it "bed-and-breakfasting".

Comment: It matches the definition of tax optimisation: https://bris-group.com/difference-tax-planning-tax-optimisation/ but it is a very broad term

Answer (score 15):

D Stanley gave a correct answer. Let me offer an observation. In a year where any of your investments are down, I'd suggest taking the loss (being mindful of wash sale rules), and use it to offset up to $3000 of ordinary (15%) income or to offset the tax of a Roth IRA conversion. Then in future years, continue to use the tax gain harvest strategy.

And note, that even in a year where the S&P or general market is up, one sector might be down. This depends on what type of indexes you are tracking.

Comment: To harvest capital losses, do your investments have to be long term?

Comment: No. If all you have taken is a loss, it's a loss. For active traders, we need to first offset long-tern gains against long term losses, short against short, etc. For you, this would be a non-issue.

Comment: Awesome, good stuff here. I see your edit mentions sectors of the the S&P being down during an up year, but I thought that for tax purposes, my share of the index was what counted, not the individual stocks comprising it.

Comment: It sounds like you have a broad index fund. No problem. Look at the Spiders ETFs, and you'll see how you might have sector indexes. But don't take this as 'advice'.

Comment: haha, of course. Friendly, not professional advice. I see now how dividing your assets into different sectors can be beneficial, at least for harvesting losses. Next time I sell I'll give some thought into splitting it up. Yes, I use the S&P 500.

Comment: This is useful info, but it's not an answer to the question.

Comment: This is an absolutely excellent idea.... I'm kind of shocked it never occurred to me to hold sector funds in my taxable account to harvest the tax efficiency....

Comment: @quid, thx. Fees may be slightly higher. Do the math to see if the cost is offset by the savings this strategy creates.

Comment: @BrenBarn - agreed, it was really an add-on to the accepted answer. But too long for comment.

Answer (score 4):

One term for what you have done is **"reset your cost basis"**.